# Creating a Notifications type feed in GAE Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm working on a notification feed for my mobile app and am looking for some help on an issue.

The app is a Twitter/Facebook like app where users can post statuses and other users can like, comment, or subscribe to them.

One thing I want to have in my app is to have a notifications feed where users can see who liked/comment on their post or subscribed to them.

The first part of this system I have figured out, when a user likes/comments/subscribes, a `Notification` entity will be written to the datastore with details about the event. To show a users `Notification`'s all I have to do is query for all `Notification`'s for that user, sort by date created desc and we have a nice little feed of actions other users took on a specific users account.

The issue I have is what to do when someone unlikes a post, unsubscribes or deletes a comment. Currently, if I were to query for that specific notification, it is possible that nothing would return from the datastore because of eventual consistency. We could imagine someone liking, then immediate unliking a post (b/c who hasn't done that? =P). The query to find that `Notification` might return null and nothing would get deleted when calling `ofy().delete().entity(notification).now();` And now the user has a notification in their feed saying Sally liked his post when in reality she liked then quickly unliked it!

A wrench in this whole system is that I cannot delete by `Key<Notification>`, because I don't really have a way to know `id` of the `Notification` when trying to delete it.

A potential solution I am experimenting with is to not delete any `Notification`s. Instead I would always write `Notification`'s and simply indicate if the notification was positive or negative. Then in my query to display notifications to a specific user, I could somehow only display the sum-positive `Notification`'s. This would save some money on datastore too because deleting entities is expensive.

Comment: well for rapid sequential liking and unliking you could simply debounce that action on the client side, wait +/- 5 seconds until the result becomes stable and then, and only then, send the request to the server to perform the actual like / no-more-like persist operation.

Comment: @konqi Good idea. Still would like this API system to be solid though!

Comment: The same would work on the server side, might require some memcache and task queue use though. Or you could just add locking, say: If you liked a notification you cannot unlike it for 10 seconds, all you'd need for that is a timestamp (and again maybe some memcache). This would also reduce your datastore writes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main ways I've solved this problem before:

1. deterministic key

   for example

{user-Id}-{post-id}-{liked-by} for likes

{user-id}-{post-id}-{comment-by}-{comment-index} for comments

This will work for most basic use cases for the problem you defined, but you'll have some hairy edge cases to figure out (like managing indexes of comments as they get edited and deleted). This will allow get and delete by key

2. parallel data structures

The idea here is to create more than one entity at a time in a transaction, but to make sure they have related keys. For example, when someone comments on a feed item, create a Comment entity, then create a CommentedOn entity which has the same ID, but make it have a parent key of the commenter user.

Then, you can make a strongly consistent query for the CommentedOn, and use the same id to do a get by key on the Comment. You can also just store a key, rather than having matching IDs if that's too hard. Having matching IDs in practice was easier each time I did this.

The main limitation of this approach is that you're effectively creating an index yourself out of entities, and while this can give you strongly consistent queries where you need them the throughput limitations of transactional writes can become harder to understand. You also need to manage state changes (like deletes) carefully.

3. State flags on entities

Assuming the Notification object just shows the user that something happened but links to another entity for the actual data, you could store a state flag (deleted, hidden, private etc) on that entity. Then listing your notifications would be a matter of loading the entities server side and filtering in code (or possibly subsequent filtered queries).

At the end of the day, the complexity of the solution should mirror the complexity of the problem. I would start with approach 3 then migrate to approach 2 when the fuller set of requirements is understood. It is a more robust and flexible approach, but complexity of XG transaction  limitations will rear its head - but ultimately a distributed feed like this is a hard problem.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! You have given me some new ideas I can use here for sure. I like approach 3 and approach 2 is something I have never thought of doing.

Comment: What are the transaction limitations one could run into that you mentioned?

Comment: An XG transaction is limited to 25 root entity keys, and the documented throughput limit is 1/sec for a root entity (in reality maybe 5/sec or so). Parallel data structures use more root entities to achieve strongly consistent queries,  but other concurrent transactions (within the same second for example) may only use one of the entities involved, but coupled with other entities. The throughput characteristics for distinct XG transactions that are couple only by effecting the same root entities are not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing and what worked for my specific model was that before creating a `Notification` Entity I would first allocate and ID for it:

```
 // Allocate an ID for a Notification
 final Key<Notification> notificationKey = factory().allocateId(Notification.class);
 final Long notificationId = notificationKey.getId();
```

Then when creating my `Like` or `Follow` Entity, I would set the property `Like.notificationId = notificationId;` or `Follow.notificationId = notificationId;`

Then I would save both Entities.

Later, when I want to delete the `Like` or `Follow` I can do so and at the same time get the Id of the `Notification`, load the `Notification` by key (which is strongly consistent to do so), and delete it too.

Just another approach that may help someone =D

Comment: It is probably more convenient to store the notificationId as a Ref<>, this makes it easier to work with in general, and has the advantage that it encodes the full key, rather than just an ID, which is beneficial if you need to change parent key hierarchies down the road. That allows you to avoid a full data migration. They also work better in the datastore explorer, because datastore Keys are first class types.